# command inside the os.system() not working

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, os.system

I'm using the os.system() module to execute copy/b windows command but its not working as well as not generating any error. It is simply returning 0 in the editor nothing else.
i have used subprocess but this one also didn't work. Can someone fix this

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir("E:\\movies\\movie\\New folder\\temp\\process\\")

wd="E:\\movies\\movie\\New folder\\temp\\process\\"
lis=[]
for i in glob.glob("E:\\movies\\movie\\New folder\\temp\\process\\*"):
    lis.append(i)

for j in lis: 
    print(i)
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("\n\n")

for i in lis:
    status=os.system('cmd /k "copy/b *. 100.mp4"')
    #subprocess.call('cmd /c "copy/b *. 100.mp4"',shell=True)
    print(status)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the `cmd /k` wrapping? Also, is your command supposed to actually care about the value of `i`? If not, then what is the loop for?

Comment: Why do you have the `"copy/b *. 100.mp4"` portion surrounded with double quotes?

Comment: @martineau, the quotes are important in some cases (but not this case) to prevent CMD from corrupting the first argument. Without them, a first argument like "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" will get executed as `C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"`, for which the shell will try to execute "C:\Program". If we wrap the whole command line in quotes, CMD strips them and the command is processed as intended. subprocess does this for `shell=True`, but we have to do it manually for `os.system`.

Comment: There's no reason for the OP's additional `cmd /c` or `cmd /k` in the command line. The command is already executed via `cmd.exe /c`. And the actual command line, `"copy/b *. 100.mp4"`, has nothing to do with any of the previous code that globs `lis`. I don't know what the goal is here.

Comment: @ErykSun: Thanks, although I generally know when they are needed and was just asking the OP why they were using them when they weren't — on the theory that might be part of the problem — but your explanation of the rules is good information for the OP to know (since they obviously don't).

Comment: Droop: Your code doesn't actually use the `lis` list anywhere after creating it, which means it will simply execute the exact same copy command over and over — which is at least part of the problem it "didn't work". Also note that `glob,glob()` returns a list of any matching files, so you could simple do `lis = glob.glob("E:\\movies\\movie\\New folder\\temp\\process\\*")` to do what your code is doing — although that won't help because of the first issue I mentioned.